# Page refresh prevents appending of HTML to DOM

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a hover menu but due to hover limitations on mobile devices (the user cannot click to a page and keep the menu on the screen as it disappears on page refresh) I have created the following function that should enable them to do this however when the page refreshes the menu is not being appended to the DOM (I can see it for a split second on the screen before the page refreshes). Any ideas why?

```
$('ul.dropdown').empty().append(localStorage.getItem("listHTML"));
```

Function -

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //on mobile only due to hover limitations -
        //(we desire to click a parent menu link that goes to its homepage AND show the hover menu that was clicked and its children)
        //therefore we want to send the user to the homepage of the clicked menu item (parent)
        //AND display its sub menu items (children) again in a menu.
        if ($(window).width() <= 939) {


            $("li.sub-level").click(function () {


                    if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {

                        var listHTML = $(this).find(".dropdown").html();
                        var nodeTITLE = $(this).children().clone().html();

                        localStorage.setItem("listHTML", listHTML);
                        localStorage.setItem("nodeTITLE", nodeTITLE);

                        //test stubs
                        alert(listHTML);
                        alert(nodeTITLE);

                }
                else {

                        alert('Your browser does not support HTML5 storage, please report this.')
                    }


                //at this point remove the class that stops this link from executing the anchor and take the user to target page
                $(this).removeClass("has-dropdown");


                //alert('about to write the listHTML into the DOM');

                //now finally append the listHTML to the menu as the page has refreshed - 
                //NOT WORKING AS PAGE REFRESH WIPING OUT THE HTML!
                $('ul.dropdown').empty().append(localStorage.getItem("listHTML"));

            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

HTML -

```
<ul class="dropdown"><li class="title back js-generated"><h5><a href="#">Back</a></h5></li>
            <li>

                <a href="http://scotsman.v6hotelsites.local/scotsman-hotel/about/" target="">
Introducing the Scotsman
                </a>

            </li>
            <li>

                <a href="http://scotsman.v6hotelsites.local/scotsman-hotel/about/history/" target="_self">
History
                </a>

            </li>
            <li>

                <a href="http://scotsman.v6hotelsites.local/scotsman-hotel/about/concierge/" target="_self">
Concierge
                </a>

            </li>
            <li>

                <a href="http://scotsman.v6hotelsites.local/scotsman-hotel/about/location/" target="_self">
Location
                </a>

            </li>
            <li>

                <a href="http://scotsman.v6hotelsites.local/scotsman-hotel/about/hotel-services/" target="_self">
Hotel Services
                </a>

            </li>
    </ul>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the value of `localStorage.getItem("listHTML")` when you append then new listHTML

Comment: Hi Kees the extracted HTML has been added to the edited post above

Comment: Hi Bob, sitll missing some context (the .sub-level and .dropdown elements for instance)

Comment: Hi Kees The .sub-level is up a level and  have amended the HTML

Comment: OK I get it now :)